# Angular2 jwt auth via interceptor in submodule

Tags: angular, jwt

I have an app with several modules following the suggested architecture in [post](https://medium.com/@cyrilletuzi/architecture-in-angular-projects-242606567e40). I need to know the correct configuration and positioning in the project folder structure of an Interceptor for the task of attach an Authorization header with Bearer Token using the @auth0/angular-jwt library, as well as the module import structure. I have a core module factorizing the common module imports but **I would like to restrict the particular feature of this autorization to my custom business logic module.** Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the sub module contain any components? 
Example : Login Component.ts

Comment: yes, and also a service related with all the auth endpoints in my api

Comment: and this is a lazy loaded module right?

Comment: no, it is not, but it would be nice to know the treatment in that case too

Comment: I don't want to have mixed code associated with authentication in the app module. Currently I have the interceptors in the providers of the app module, as well as the `JwtModule.forRoot ...` in the imports

Comment: Hope you know the concept of lazy lading?

Comment: this interceptors (the way i see things) are are typical of my submodule, since in the case of my app, authentication is not a feature that is necessarily associated with the entire application, in a general sense I want to keep separation of concerns, because i want to reuse the auth submodule for future apps with similar cases

Comment: yes, prior to the current implementation several of my modules were lazy loaded, but this is not a big app, and those modules aren't heavy and they are necessary in any moment of the app flow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { ModuleWithProviders, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LoadingComponent } from '../components/home/shared/loading/loading.component';
import { JwtModule, JWT_OPTIONS } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { JwtService } from '../util';


export function jwtOptionsFactory(jwtService: JwtService) {
  return {
    tokenGetter: () => {
      return jwtService.getToken();
    }
  };
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      jwtOptionsProvider: {
        provide: JWT_OPTIONS,
        useFactory: jwtOptionsFactory,
        deps: [JwtService]
      }
    })
  ],
  declarations: [LoadingComponent],
  exports: [JwtModule],
})
export class AuthModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AuthModule
    };
  }
}
```

Add `AuthModule.forRoot()` to imports of app.module.ts

Comment: As of 2023 ModuleWithProviders is generic so should be ModuleWithProviders<AuthModule>

Answer (score 0):

This configuration must be in the **app.module.ts** file. E.g:

```js
// other imports...
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

export function tokenGetter(): string {
    return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    // your declarations...
  ],
  imports: [
    // your imports...
    JwtModule.forRoot({
        config: {
            tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
            whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000'],
            blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/api/auth']
        }
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    // your providers...
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: app.module.ts is commonly used for root level module configurations, in the particular case of my app the auth feature isn't a root level feature. I want to restrict this feature only to a submodule, "the auth module" for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you have lazy loaded modules in your project.
then you can use disallowedRoutes feature of auth0/angular-jwt library

[**disallowedRoutes**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt#disallowedroutes-array)

If you do not want to replace the authorization headers for specific routes, list them in the disallowedRoutes. This can be useful if your initial auth route(s) are on an allowed domain and take basic auth headers. These routes need to be prefixed with the correct protocol (Http://, https://). If you want to add a route to the list of disallowed routes regardless of the protocol, you can prefix it with //.

```
JwtModule.forRoot({
  config: {
    // ...
    disallowedRoutes: [
      "http://localhost:3001/auth/",
      "https://foo1.com/bar/",
      "//foo1.com/bar/baz",
      /localhost:3001\/foo\/far.*/,
    ], // strings and regular expressions
  },
});
```

Comment: I'm looking for a configuration in which I don't have to include code for the security feature in the app module, I want to know if it is possible to include this in a sub-module, making the maintaining more feasible